# What are the most popular database vendors based on market share?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database, oracle

I am wondering if anyone can point me to research or a link to statistics regarding popularity of database deployment. Obviously, MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer are some of the major players but I am looking for actual data on market share. Any data or site with chart/graphs etc would be good with preference for change in market share over time.

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are the same vendor.

Answer (score 10):

People pay research firms like [Gartner](http://www.gartner.com/technology/home.jsp) gobs and gobs and gobs of money for this data. I do not expect you to get reliable information from individual vendor sites or from the opinions of folks here on ServerFault (as well-meaning as they may be). If you hold this information highly valuable, and want to rely on authenticity and currency, I suggest you hit up a research firm that specializes in it, subscribe to their newsletter, offer sacrifices to their pagan deities, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice diagram that should answer your question, [from MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/marketshare/).

Comment: You have to watch out for stuff on vendor sites.  People promoting products tend to cherry pick the numbers that make their product look best.

Comment: @JOTN That diagram sounded pretty clean, checking around. I agree, some companies have no scruples about doing that kind of unfair practice (MS I'm looking at you), but it does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: Why bash MS? Did they hurt you as a child? They're no different than Oracle, General Motors, or any other company. They're no more or less "evil" then any other company that's out to be the market leader, regardless of industry or product. Repeat: Microsoft is not an evil empire, at least not any more than any other company.

Comment: @joeqwerty Please don't tell me I'm *bashing* MS. They're known for having published *independent* statistics that were - later - proven to be directly or indirectly paid by MS. This was a few years ago. Not sure as of today, though [well, there was something a few weeks ago on slashdot.net about that...]

Comment: And my question is: Has no other company ever done that? Has Apple or IBM never spun information to suit their needs? I'm just curious as to why everyone looks askance at MS but never seem to mention every other company that engages in the same behavior, as they all do.

Comment: Disregarding the comments above, the information is also at least 3 years old.

Comment: Why do they show that most organizations have multiple databases installed? Those numbers don't really add up do they?

Answer (score 3):

That's a difficult question to answer.  Market share can mean a lot of different things.  Is it the number of companies that use it, the number of processors it's installed on, the licensing revenue, the database size, the number of operations performed, etc.  What's the goal of trying to figure it out?  If it's about which is better for employment, you would want to look at open positions and salary stats.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft frequently advertises that SQL Server database engine has been downloaded and installed more than anything else.

Comment: Given that SQL Express is included with products like Office (depending on the version) and that it's included by default with Visual Studio installs that's probably true or at least close to it.  Also SQL Server compact edition is included in every single Windows OS which is installed as Media player uses compact edition, which while a crappy approach to take would technically be legit as that is a version of the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link

http://www.tdan.com/view-featured-columns/15299

There are several archived versions as well which may have the specif charts your are looking for.